Accessing I2C registers of IMX415 using Jetson AGX Orin
I had set the bit 0 of a camera register of IMX415 - 0x3030 to 1 to horizontally invert an image using the command:
sudo i2cset -y -f 2 0x54 0x30 0x30 0x01 i
running this command does not give any error but I am not able to check if the register is set using i2cget command and the operation of horizontal inversion is also not showing.
Also, before i got two address in i2cbus 2 as 0x34 and 0x54, now only 0x54 is showing, is 0x34 the slave address? but it is not showing so can we use 0x54?
